# using localStorage offline app ... how do I make different file source (domain name) for each copy of the app

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on making an offline form app that I can place in various subfolders and the app saves localStorage information.  I want each copy of the app to save its own localStorage, however, it all deems the original source/domain name as "file://".  I understand that localStorage is filed under the domain name and therefore "file://" is considered the domain name for localStorage.   How can I change the file/domain name to be different based upon the .html file location?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Instead:

- Install a web server on your machine (they're not that big) and add a name for each version of the app you want to run to your machine's name resolution (`/etc/hosts` on *nix, etc.) — e.g. `app1.local`, `app2.local` — and access them via HTTP. They'll each get their own local storage.
- Very much as a second-best solution: Use a page-specific prefix (which you can derive from `location`) on every local storage key.

Comment: Thank you.  The page-specific prefix idea may be the way to go for me.  I just gotta figure out how to do that .. it can't be all that difficult.  Its like making a variable variable.  Thanks again.

Comment: UPDATE: I got it working with a prefix derived from the path name.  Thanks again.